# Is there a way to display the Error Message in SAP BusinessObjects notifications?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I see there are placeholders such as `%SI_NAME%` and `SI_OWNER` but what I'm looking for is the ability to actually send the Error Message (e.g. `Error in File Parameter has no value. Details: errorKind`) in the failure notification email to make it easier to get the errors without having to go into the system to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a way to do this.  The actual error message is stored in a property named **SI_STATUSINFO**, but it is a property bag and not a string, so it does not work as a placeholder.